# Perform an action from a condition for a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, if-statement

***I have the following dataframe:***

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame ({'example': ['ACETATO MOLOCUATO']})
```

**The condition is that if the string ends in "ATO" I will choose only the first three words. The way I planted it is as follows:**

**#If the example ends in "ATO"**

```
df ['example']. str.contains ('ATO $')
```

**#Then Extract the first 3 words**

```
df ['example']. str.extract ('(\ w +) \ s (\ w +) \ s (\ w +)')
```

**#Otherwise, print the dataframe without changes**

I would like to know the best way to relate this last action based on the first condition.

Comment: You need to extract the 3 words in what format ?  Put into separate columns or all in one column (e.g. as a list of words or separated by comma) ?   Please advise your expected output.   Also please modify your sample data to includes cases of 3 or more words.

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
>>> df
                      example
0  W1 W2 W3 ACETATO MOLOCUATO
1          NOTHING TO DO HERE
```

Filter and apply:

```
mask = df["example"].str.endswith("ATO")  # condition
df.loc[mask, "example"] = df.loc[mask, "example"] \
                            .apply(lambda s:  " ".join(s.split(" ")[:3]))
```

Output result:

```
>>> df
              example
0            W1 W2 W3
1  NOTHING TO DO HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
df = df.join(df.loc[df ['example'].str.endswith('ATO'), 'example'].str.extract(r'(?P<Word1>\w+)(?:\s+(?P<Word2>\w+))?(?:\s+(?P<Word3>\w+))?'))
```

Here, we use `.str.endswith()` to check for the condition of end of that target string.  Then we use `.loc` to locate the rows with this condition to further use `.str.extract()` to extract the first 3 words.  Hence, the word extraction will be acted only on the strings ends with the target string.  This should answer your question of:

> I would like to know the best way to relate this last action based on
> the first condition.

The regex used for `.str.extract()` is as follows:

```
(?P<Word1>\w+)(?:\s+(?P<Word2>\w+))?(?:\s+(?P<Word3>\w+))?
```

**Regex features:**

1. It allows extraction of 1, 2 or 3 words (no need to have all 3 words).  Note that your regex returns nothing matched if there is/are only 1 or 2 words.
2. ***Named Capturing Group*** is used to format the names of 3 new columns

### Demo

**Data setup:**

```
data = {'example': ['ACETATO MOLOCUATO',
  'WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4_ATO',
  'WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

                       example
0            ACETATO MOLOCUATO
1  WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4_ATO
2      WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4
```

**Run new code:**

```
df = df.join(df.loc[df ['example'].str.endswith('ATO'), 'example'].str.extract(r'(?P<Word1>\w+)(?:\s+(?P<Word2>\w+))?(?:\s+(?P<Word3>\w+))?'))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)


                       example    Word1      Word2  Word3
0            ACETATO MOLOCUATO  ACETATO  MOLOCUATO    NaN
1  WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4_ATO    WORD1      WORD2  WORD3
2      WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4      NaN        NaN    NaN
```

#### If you want to put the results in one column, you can do:

```
df['3_words'] = df[['Word1', 'Word2', 'Word3']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)


                       example    Word1      Word2  Word3            3_words
0            ACETATO MOLOCUATO  ACETATO  MOLOCUATO    NaN  ACETATO MOLOCUATO
1  WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4_ATO    WORD1      WORD2  WORD3  WORD1 WORD2 WORD3
2      WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4      NaN        NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [SeaBean's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67769422/3832970) with optional capturing groups, but with a single call to `Series.str.extract`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({'example': ['ACETATO MOLOCUATO','WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4_ATO', 'WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4']})
df[['Word_1', 'Word_2', 'Word_3']] = df['example'].str.extract(r'^(?=.*ATO$)(\w+)(?:\s+(\w+))?(?:\s+(\w+))?')
# >>> df
#                        example   Word_1     Word_2 Word_3
# 0            ACETATO MOLOCUATO  ACETATO  MOLOCUATO    NaN
# 1  WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4_ATO    WORD1      WORD2  WORD3
# 2      WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4      NaN        NaN    NaN
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7gWTqa/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*ATO$)` - the string must end with `ATO`
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(?:\s+(\w+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or more whitespaces and then capturing into Group 2 any one or more word chars
- `(?:\s+(\w+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or more whitespaces and then capturing into Group 3 any one or more word chars.